# MySQL select items such that all values match for that item

Tags: mysql

For example, I have a test id (1st column) and a result (2nd column):

```
id | result
1  | 6
1  | 6
2  | 7
2  | 6
3  | 8
```

I only want to know tests such that for a given test, every result matched. I should get:

```
1
3
```

Conversely, I want every test such that not every result matched, which in this example would result in:

```
2
```

Comment: Please add a minimal piece of code to show what you got already.

Comment: coming up with the correct search query is just as hard as coming up with the correct mysql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT test_id FROM test GROUP BY test_id HAVING MAX(result) = MIN(result)
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/903025/3/0